# Is there a way to only mark the most recent email in a thread as unread?

Tags: macos, mail.app

Right-click -> Mark as Unread marks every email in the thread as unread.

I am using MacOS 10.14.6 and Mail 12.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a message thread in the mail app, there's a small indicator of how many messages are in the thread:

[image: message thread]

If you click on that indicator, it'll open up the thread and show all the individual messages:

[image]

You can then interact with the individual messages, including setting the most recent one as unread.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that was clickable. Thank you.